# Trouble listening for updates in state with using Riverpod in flutter

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Trying to learn riverpod by building the flutter counter app and using a `StateNotifierProvider` to update the count. The trouble is I can't get the count to update. Here is all of my code.

The state class:

```
class CounterState{
  int count;

  CounterState({this.count = 0});

  CounterState copyWith({required int updatedCounter}) =>
      CounterState(count: updatedCounter);
}
```

The `StateNotifier` and `StateNotifierProvider`

```
final counterProvider = StateNotifierProvider<CounterController, CounterState>(
(ref) => CounterController(CounterState()));

class CounterController extends StateNotifier<CounterState>{
  CounterController(CounterState state) : super(state);

  int currentCount() => state.count;

  void addCount(){
    state = state.copyWith(updatedCounter: state.count+1);
    debugPrint(state.count.toString()); // <-- prints the correct value of count
  }
}
```

My ConsumerWidget:

```
class MyHomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Riverpod counter"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              ref.watch(counterProvider.notifier).currentCount().toString(),
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: ref.read(counterProvider.notifier).addCount ,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Why is the count not updating on the UI when it is getting updated on the `StateNotifier` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your currentCount method does not change with the new state. Remove it and do this in your widget

```
ref.watch(counterProvider).count.toString(),
```